# All subsets of nonnegative integers such that $a+2b = n$ has one solution for every positive integer n

Tags: combinatorics

My friend tackled this problem awhile ago and gave it to me recently. To reiterate, I am trying to find all subsets $S$ of the nonnegative integers such that the equation $a+2b = n$, **where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $S$**, has one solution for every positive integer $n$.

One could also try extending the prompt to all subsets $S$ of the integers.

Comment: $S=\{0,1\}$ doesn't work because $n=4$ has no solution.  A solution might start $S=\{0,1,4,5,12,13,...\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
The sequence might start $S=\{0,1,4,5,16,17,20,21,64,...\}$
Write them in base 4.